# Need to run cron job for my php file on hosting server

Tags: php, linux, cron, hosting

I have php file on my linux hosting server and i want to execute it 2 times a day. Below is my link of my php file. Kindly tell me command line code for my php file.

http://viewpackages.com/prices/generator/footer.php

See attached image which is my hosting cron job form. Tell me what i have to write in command line text field
[click here to see image of my hosting cron job form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FrOj.png)

Comment: find out the location of footer.php on your web server? what is your hosting server?

Comment: go in your terminal and run `man cron`, then `man crontab` and maybe you meant `man man`

Comment: see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FrOj.png. i have to add something in this form of my hosting. but i don't know what to write

Comment: i added  php file link in my question which i want to add in cron job to run 2 times every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pasting this on the command option:

```
wget -O /dev/null http://viewpackages.com/prices/generator/footer.php
```

Test it and tell me if there's anything wrong

Comment: @SaddamHussain Do mark this answer as accepted so this can be closed.

Comment: how to close it... i don't know... kindly tell me

Comment: Simply click the tick mark near my answer and it'll turn green. This means that this question is closed as it have an answer.